# Is there a "learner's permit" for pilots?

Tags: flight-training, pilot-certification

To get a driver's license (in Oregon), you have to pass a written test, get an instruction permit, get 100 hours of supervised driving practice, take a drive test, then get your driver's license, at which point you can drive alone.

I know pilots have to get a certain number of supervised flying hours, and can then get a pilot's license and fly alone. Is there an equivalent of the instruction permit, or can you just start flying as long as there's a licensed pilot who can take over?

Comment: Someone will be along with a more comprehensive answer I'm sure, but here's one tidbit to get you going: flying solo is not only *allowed* before going up for your full pilot's license test, it is a *requirement*!

Comment: @randomhead oh, that's interesting; what's the point of that? Since nobody's in the plane to make sure you fly well, how does it determine anything other than "you can fly alone without crashing"? Surely that's determined before someone can fly solo?

Comment: I suggest starting here: [How to become a pilot.](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/become)  After reviewing that, you can come back here with more specific questions.

Comment: @Gerry thank you! So it looks like the process is basically get a medical exam, take flying lessons, get a student pilot certificate which is analogous to a learner's permit, take more flying lessons, fly solo, pass a "practical test" analogous to the drive test, then get a pilot's license?

Comment: Don't forget 'ground school' where you learn theory, weather, rules of the air, navigation, etc. Then you can take the 'Written exam' (it's actually computerized.) It generally helps if you get started on this before you start actual flying. It also helps to have some dollars saved in the bank. Once you start flying, it helps to fly regularly (weekly). If you drag it out you lose retention and have go over stuff again and that just means more flying and more hours and more money. Despite what the rules say, most students take about 50-60 hours to get their certificate.

Comment: @someone, your last comment is the perfect answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start flying and *logging the training time* received from a certified flight instructor without meeting any other practical requirements. If the flight time will *not* be logged, there is no regulation that prevents you from *flying an airplane* as long as there is a pilot on board. (There are of course implicit requirements here such as this pilot be acting as the pilot in command and can't just literally "be on board", drunk in the back seat, without a valid medical certificate, in a plane for which they are not rated, etc.)

In your example above, the parallel to the instruction permit in aviation is the student pilot certificate. The student pilot certificate, along with a medical certificate, (and relevant endorsements from your flight instructor) are required only when you fly *solo*.

While you can (and will, should you pursue your license) read about the various requirements in the [CFRs](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61) for example [14 CFR 61.51(h)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.51#p-61.51(h)), the following FAA page [Become a Pilot](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/become/student_cert) is a more accessible reference that may answer some common related questions.